# How can get Google to index a URL with a canonical tag?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

We have the URL routes with the schema: `/ads/:city`.
The objective is to get URLs that use this route indexed in Google:

- `/ads/joinville`
- `/ads/lages`
- `/ads/florianopolis`

Today, Google Search Console reports all the pages are canonical of  `/ads/lages` even though each page has its own unique canonical tag.  For example, the canonical tag for `/ads/florianopolis` is: `<link rel="canonical" href="https://example.com/ads/florianopolis" />`

How we can get Google to index all these URLs?

Comment: Canonical tags are only a hint to Google.   What content is on the pages?  How different is it between different cities?

Comment: The content is just a list of images with descriptions and heading. The pages are different cities and the HTML is the same.

Comment: Are the images and headings unique for each city?

Comment: No, the images are totally different and the title is similar it just change the name of the city.

Comment: My guess is that with such a small amount of unique text on the page, Google is struggling to understand that the pages are different.   They may even look like [doorway pages](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/doorway-pages) to Google.

Comment: Why do you have `/ads/` in the URL path?  Are these URLs related to advertisements?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Yes, are advertisements for each city.

Comment: Ads are not usually great content for search engines to index.   I'd recommend using `noindex` on them so they don't hurt the rest of your site.